# Does MySQL support Intel's AES-NI instructions?

Tags: mysql, encryption, intel

I know that MySQL has the AES_ENCRYPT and AES_DECRYPT instructions; do they use Intel's AES-NI instructions? Are there other encryption options in MySQL and do they support AES-NI?

Secondly, if MySQL does not support AES-NI, does MariaDB?

For full database encryption - preferably Transparent Database Encryption or TDE - does it exist for MySQL (preferably open source) and does it support AES-NI?

(By the way, I already know about full disk encryption; this is an investigation into just some of the alternatives.)

Answer (score 0):

MySQL needn't support AES-NI - it's in the "wrong" part of the stack.  Support for AES-NI would come from the underlying operating system kernel (Linux, Windows).  If you are running MySQL on Linux, with AES-NI support, you will receive transparent acceleration benefits for the MySQL workload.

Comment: Since when is this the case? Even the latest MySQL 5.5 builds don't show any reference of the Linux Crypto API (which does support AES-NI) being used.